# Creating second level nav with ReactRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a template like this:
[image]

I am trying to create tabs in component using router, but getting errors.

My `index.js` is

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    render
} from 'react-dom'
import {
    Provider as ReduxProvider
} from 'react-redux'
// import { Provider as IntlProvider } from './components/Intl'
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,
    Link,
    Redirect,
    browserHistory
} from 'react-router'


import  App  from './containers/App'
import  Home  from './containers/Home/Home'
import  Course  from './containers/Course/Course'
import  Feedback  from './containers/Feedback/Feedback'
import  Revenue from './containers/Revenue/Revenue'
import  Income from './containers/Revenue/Income'
import  IncomeOver from './containers/Revenue/IncomeOver'

render((
    <ReduxProvider >
        <IntlProvider locale={'en'}>
          <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
                <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
                <Route path="Course" component={Course}/>
                <Route path="Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
                <Route path="/Revenue" component={Revenue}>
                    <Route path="Income" component={Income}/>
                    <Route path="IncomeOver" component={IncomeOver}/>

                </Route>
            </Route>

          </Router>
        </IntlProvider>
  </ReduxProvider>
), document.getElementById('mount'))
```

Menu works only for left bar.

Try do same for tabs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

 function Revenue ({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
    <div>
              <ul>
                  <li><Link to="/Income" activeClassName="activelink">1111 </Link></li>
                  <li><Link to="/IncomeOver" activeClassName="activelink">2222 </Link></li>

              </ul>
          </div>
      <div className="cont-position">{children}</div>
    </div>

  )
}
export default Revenue
```

But it not working for me. How to fix this problem? I need something like tabs. Open page and there component's switching by clicking links

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just register them on one level like this

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
   <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
   <Route path="Course" component={Course}/>
   <Route path="Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
   <Route path="/Revenue" component={Revenue}/>
   <Route path="/Revenue/Income" component={Income}/>
   <Route path="/Revenue/IncomeOver" component={IncomeOver}/>
 </Route>
```

and use them later like this

```
<Link to="/Revenue/Income" activeClassName="activelink">1111 </Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's not working, you may need to provide more details, but try this out:

in those two lines:

```
            <Route path="Course" component={Course}/>
            <Route path="Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
```

add / to the path like that:

```
            <Route path="/Course" component={Course}/>
            <Route path="/Feedback" component={Feedback}/>
```

remove this :

```
             <Route path="/Revenue" component={Revenue}>
                <Route path="Income" component={Income}/>
                <Route path="IncomeOver" component={IncomeOver}/>

            </Route>
```

replace it by:

```
         <Route path="/" component={Revenue}>
            <Route path="Revenue" component={Revenue}>
                <Route path="Income" component={Income}/>
                <Route path="IncomeOver" component={IncomeOver}/>

            </Route>
          </Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "exact"

```html
<Route exact path='/Revenue' component={Revenue}/>
<Route exact path='/Revenue/Income' component={Income}/>
```